# Converting (parsing?) character string of Facebook fancount data using R

Tags: r

I need to extract Facebook country likes for a number of brands. My problem is I dont even know where to start - I have spent the past 4 hours searching but to be honest Im not even sure what to search for. I can get the data but am struggling to convert into a usable format in R for time series analysis.
Any assistance would be gratefully accepted 
The data I'm retrieving via Facebook Graph API for likes by country (of Coca-Cola is as follows:

> > > [1] "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"1542920115951985\/insights\/page_fans_country\/lifetime\",\"name\":\"page_fans_country\",\"period\":\"lifetime\",\"values\":[{\"value\":{\"BR\":17270087,\"US\":13567311,\"MX\":5674950,\"AR\":3616300,\"FR\":3409959,\"IN\":2949669,\"GB\":2670260,\"TH\":2657306,\"IT\":2401621,\"CO\":1946677,\"ID\":1921076,\"EG\":1805233,\"PK\":1665707,\"PH\":1614358,\"TR\":1607936,\"CL\":1504917,\"VN\":1384143,\"DE\":1312448,\"PL\":1201112,\"VE\":1084783,\"CA\":990114,\"RO\":932538,\"EC\":856116,\"PE\":815942,\"ES\":790320,\"AU\":759775,\"MA\":578003,\"TN\":515510,\"RS\":476986,\"NG\":476934,\"PT\":469059,\"MY\":435316,\"BE\":431930,\"ZA\":431509,\"IQ\":354145,\"SE\":352331,\"KE\":342997,\"GR\":333749,\"HU\":333281,\"NL\":330307,\"GT\":326328,\"CR\":304006,\"DZ\":300497,\"PR\":287430,\"DO\":278847},\"end_time\":\"2015-01-01T08:00:00+0000\"},{\"value\":{\"BR\":17270151,\"US\":13566624,\"MX\":5675012,\"AR\":3618242,\"FR\":3409837,\"IN\":2949969,\"GB\":2669934,\"TH\":2658044,\"IT\":2401726,\"CO\":1946797,\"ID\":1921156,\"EG\":1805337,\"PK\":1665824,\"PH\":1614402,\"TR\":1608104,\"CL\":1504979,\"VN\":1384782,\"DE\":1312138,\"PL\":1201212,\"VE\":1084776,\"CA\":990093,\"RO\":932788,\"EC\":856129,\"PE\":816002,\"ES\":790385,\"AU\":759775,\"MA\":578080,\"TN\":518210,\"RS\":477264,\"NG\":476965,\"PT\":469177,\"MY\":435296,\"ZA\":433741,\"BE\":431908,\"IQ\":364228,\"SE\":352267,\"KE\":343007,\"GR\":333771,\"HU\":333312,\"NL\":330232,\"GT\":326513,\"CR\":304021,\"DZ\":300587,\"PR\":287432,\"DO\":278892},\"end_time\":\"2015-01-02T08:00:00+0000\"}],\"title\":\"Lifetime Likes by Country\",\"description\":\"Lifetime: Aggregated Facebook location data, sorted by country, about the people who like your Page. (Unique Users)\"}],\"paging\":{\"previous\":\"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/cocacola\/insights\/page_fans_country?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAMLTB1Ufx44l8Q2hT34jxjmVjONPzhqncAvv985cUXOY6Q9FZBLuL3OM8oLXDPTBroD5DY8SS9ZBd1OIhSAMwjrISQRgWh5kkJVu75Ss7aWESIlKrwBLyLt6VYHUEUlUlmCV72TSQGZBkkOeE4OaZA4gvHIZBngZDZD&since=1419897600&until=1420070400\",\"next\":\"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/cocacola\/insights\/page_fans_country?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAMLTB1Ufx44l8Q2hT34jxjmVjONPzhqncAvv985cUXOY6Q9FZBLuL3OM8oLXDPTBroD5DY8SS9ZBd1OIhSAMwjrISQRgWh5kkJVu75Ss7aWESIlKrwBLyLt6VYHUEUlUlmCV72TSQGZBkkOeE4OaZA4gvHIZBngZDZD&since=1420243200&until=1420416000\"}}"

This data is for two days and the data I need to retrieve start from line 3 (BR has 17270087 fans for Coca-Cola) and ends on line 10 (DO has 278847 fans) plus the date (indicated by end time of 2015-01-01). I then need to repeat the extract for line 12 to line 19 plus the end time of 2015-01-02 for each of the country references. Ideally I also want to capture the Facebook ID on line 2 (1542920115951985) to be able to build a data frame with Facebook ID, Date, Country and Likes in each record.

Comment: That looks like JSON text, so I'd start by installing one of the JSON parsing packages like *rjson*, *jsonlite*, and *RJSONIO* and then start reading their documentation.

Comment: Maybe give [rfacebook](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook) a try. Version 0.3 is available on CRAN, 0.4 on github. It seems to have a lot of useful functions implemented already.

Section _Analyzing data from a Facebook page_ on the [github page](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook#analyzing-data-from-a-facebook-page) shows an example by analyzing the page _Humans of New York_.

Comment: thanks for the tips guys. I tried the RFacebook option (been using it for a while but wasnt aware of extra parameters on "getInsights". It gives me exactly what I need